# With a cartridge BB if the shell threads are aligned on the same axis can the cartridge be unthreaded drive side with NDS cup in place?

Tags: bottom-bracket, alignment

If the BB shell's drive-side and NDS threads are aligned on the same axis, can the cartridge be backed out of the drive side while the NDS cup is still in place in the shell?

Edit: When I tried to do this as an experiment the cartridge got pulled away from the NDS bearing, so that the drive-side spindle got shorter:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Most cartridge BBs have a shoulder on the drive side, which is also the side that's integral to the bearings and spindle, plus a non-shouldered left cup. Some are the opposite, and some have no shoulders. Some have two similar cups, one of which may or may not be shouldered, and then the bearing and spindle unit is a third piece.

Drive vs non-drive side is unimportant to the question you're asking. Shouldered vs non-shouldered is though. What's important is that when you're done, it's all properly torqued against each other. If there's a shouldered side, that needs to be torqued against the frame, and the non-shouldered side needs to be torqued against the main BB unit.

If what you're asking is if on a common BB with a shoulder on the drive side and the bearings and spindle integral to that piece, and an unshouldered left cup, whether you can leave the left cup untouched when you take the the main unit out, no, that's not really ideal. Unscrewing the drive side in that situation can easily rotate the NDS side out a little, such that when you reinstall the DS, proper contact with the NDS cup isn't made. Or, if it doesn't move at all, the ways things settle could cause you to be torqueing the BB against the left cup and not the shoulder against the shell. The better practice would be take out the DS, unscrew the NDS a turn, torque the DS back into the frame, then torque the NDS down properly against the DS.

Comment: I removed the cartridge in that way as an experiment, thinking it could confirm any thread axis misalignment.  This is a problem BB shell (and the US distributor has agreed to replace), only 67mm wide in one place and the faces not parallel, and showing signs of slight welding distortion (lift) on the NDS of the shell. The NDS hole is like a double-exposed photo of a circle. When I removed the cartridge with the NDS cup in place, there was greater resistance than usual as it was being backed out. Once removed, I saw that the NDS bearing had been pulled away from the cartridge about 5mm.

Comment: Shoulder drive-side, no shoulder NDS.

Comment: @Tim Got it, sounds frustrating. Every time I've ever dealt with a bike like that, it was fine after tapping and facing the shell, but nothing else would come close to working. There was one where the BBs I had to work with at the time were all the plastic left cup type, and it kept cracking them. Fine after tapping/facing, felt perfect.  That it's 67mm is unimportant if using something like a square taper cartridge, but would need to be corrected with a spacer to use most external BBs with it.

Comment: I described it backwards: it was the cartridge that had been pulled away from the NDS bearing -- the drive-side spindle got shorter.

Comment: @Tim Either way, it's the kind of thing that mostly only happens when the two sides are out of axis due to welding distortion. Even if something like that doesn't happen with the next one, bearing lifespan and feel will still suffer until it's fixed.

Comment: The fix would be as simple as facing and re-threading and using 1+ mm thick spacer?

Comment: Yes. It needs to be machined with piloted BB taps and then faced afterward. Shops have these tools; they're expensive. They're not re-threading it as much as letting the magic of pilots take material away from just the right places so that the BB cups can be on the same axis. The spacer isn't needed with the kind of BB you have, but if it's really 67, it would be with any of the kinds of BBs that need the shell width to be 68mm +/-0.05 etc, such as Shimano external BBs.

Comment: It's the "magic of pilots" part that I don't quite understand.I've watched the Park video on chasing threads and can follow the steps, but it seems to me that it could result in a lot of "slop" if the original weld distortion was excessive, though I don't know how to assess what the tolerances would be.  Would it be bad form if I added a drawing to my question and asked some specific questions, using it as a reference?

Comment: @Tim I don't claim to understand everything happening when piloted taps fix a distorted shell. Yes, because material is being lost, slop is increasing in some parts. I think the answer to your concern may be something along the lines of there still being so much total thread contact, it's not an issue. At the end of the day the two sides have to be in good axial alignment for the bearings to not get trashed prematurely, so if that's not achievable with tapping it, the frame is a defect.

Comment: I've been binging on Hambini Youtube videos lately, trying to get an understanding of the tolerances involved with BBs. He talks about the "slop" that is inevitable even with good threads on an aligned axis!  I don't need perfection by any means. My goal is to be able to say of a newly delivered frame "this one is good" vs "this one is a lemon".

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.  I've never seen a NDS side piece that locks into the cartridge.

---

I think you're seeing the cartridge as one part - looking something like this:

[image]

But remember its in TWO pieces - the main body that threads in from the drive side, and a much smaller supporting ring with a slight taper on the inside to support the Non-drive side.

[image: Parktool website]

The pictured unit should unscrew out the drive side once you remove the crank and spider and chainrings.
In an extreme case you might be able to reach around with sliding pliers and slowly back the whole thing out, but that would be no fun at all.

Upshot

- There are no two threads that have to align.
- Even if they did, ones a left hand thread and the other's a right hand thread in 99% of bottom brackets (french and italian BB threadings are weird)
- The NDS spacer generally has a lip that would stop it threading in too far, there's no good way to wind that all the way through the BB
- And most threaded BB shells are slightly smaller in-between the threads, because that's the metal into which the threads were cut.  That is, the crest of the threads is no-higher than the metal from which it was cut.

Comment: I assumed the cartridge could be backed out if the thread axes were aligned, that the spindle on the NDS would not move eccentrically if so.  I've added an explanation of the issue as a comment to Nathan's answer above.

Comment: The alignment I was speaking of was along the same axis. L cup ]----- axis-----[R cup